# Why does if(asynchronous.get()) work and is it ok to use it this way

Tags: javascript

When I use something like

```
if(asynchronous.get()){...}
```

And `ansynchronous.get()` is an asynchronous function, I wonder how this could ever work as the if statement isn't testing anything unless the function returns a value. Somehow I have this in my code and it works so can anyone explain to my why it works and if I should change it.

**Edit:** My assumption that my function is asynchronous was wrong, so everything is answered now.

Comment: Could you show us `console.log(asynchronous.get())`?

Comment: For example if I use `console.log(localStorage.getItem("x"));` I will get the value of the localStorage object "x".

Comment: @Julius S. localStorage.getItem is a synchronous function which will return a value immediately. See here for information about Promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @Julius S.I do not know a browser.storage object, localStorage.get is definitely synchronous, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: Yes, thanks for the link. I checked the `browser.storage.get()` method and it is asynchronous: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The if statement simply checks if the expression evaluates to a truthy value. It seems the function returns a promise, which is a function object, which is a truthy value.

The function will be executed, but you will not be able to process the result this way and the if statement will never be evaluated to false.

You need to wait for the function to resolve a value and then check the value:

```
asynchronous.get().then(val => {
    if (val) {...}
})
```